# Setting the text in the top left header cell is a Data Grid View

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

How do I set the text in the top-left header cell is a Data Grid View?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the text in the *top left header cell* by the following way

```
dataGridView.TopLeftHeaderCell.Value = "Your Text";
```

Comment: Glad..That je vous ai aidé ... Bienvenue :)